# SQL Recursive query using CTE to filter on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I'm trying to feed the output of query 1 as the input for query 2. In order to do this I'm using CTE(Common Table Expressions).

Employee Hierarchy

```
DEPT     ID     MANAGER1     MANAGER2     MANAGER3
Sales    A234   10389               19400               3049
HR       F394   29489               20403               Null
IT       H339   A234
IT       S599   39009               A234
```

**Expected output**

```
DEPT     ID     MANAGER1     MANAGER2     MANAGER3
IT       H339   A234
IT       S599   39009               A234
```

**Problem:**
Identify direct reports of managers in Sales department. in the above example ID 234 is from Sales department. His direct reports are in IT since A234 is under DIRECT_MANAGER1 and DIRECT_MANAGER2.

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT ID from Employee_Hierarchy
WHERE DEPT='Sales'
)
SELECT DEPT, ID 
FROM Employee_Hierarchy
```

But I do not know the join condition here for CTE

Comment: Seems like you need to fix the design first though, why do you have 3 manager columns?

Comment: Sadly that's how People soft is :(. That's the Manager Hierarchy eg: 3049 is A234's manager, 19400 is 3049's manager, 10389 is 19400's manager

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t think you need recursion for this. It seems like a correlated subquery is enough:

```
select e.*
from employee_hierarchy e
where exists(
    select 1
    from employee_hierarchy m
    where 
        m.id in (e.manager_id1, e.manager_id2, e.manager_id3)
        and m.dept = 'Sales'
)
```

Comment: The query takes lot of time to execute if I add `e.manager_id2, e.manager_id3`

Comment: Do you know what might be causing the query to slow down if I include multiple manager_id columns?